# assembly counting uppercase letters

Tags: assembly, counting

I want to create a program in assembly that reads string characters from the user and displays the number of uppercase letters entered. I'm using emu8086 to run assembly programs. I can;t seem to find the right program codes.I'm a newbie and I wanted to at least understand how the language works especially the symbols used. I need the representation of those valuable codes that would do counting of uppercase letters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us much about what you already know. Here is the basic code to count the uppercase characters.

```
... The counter CX was cleared beforehand

... Here AL contains the character!

cmp al,"A"
jb  Skip
cmp al,"Z"
ja  Skip
inc cx     CX will hold the result
Skip:

... Here you control your loop to iterate over the entire string
```